# Can't edit .csproj file in visual studio 2017 solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2017, csproj

Working on an ASP.NET MVC C# project in Visual Studio 2017. I cannot find .csproj file in my solution explorer.

Tried to right click the project name, and still cannot find "Edit .csproj" item as some posts suggested.

Please help!

Comment: do you work in .NET Core?

Comment: no, it is an asp.net mvc5 project

Comment: you can edit only in .NET Core using VS Otherwise you can find this file and open by notepad

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'll edit it outside of VS. Any specific reason(s) that this file being excluded in VS 2017?

Comment: on contrary, it was included in VS 2017 new format

Comment: Hi Alexan, did you mean that csproj file is included in VS 2017 solution explorer? can you elaborate it further on this topic?

Comment: no, it isn't included, but you can edit it in VS 2017 for .NET Core projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project file editing feature (without needing to unload the project) is part of the new CPS-based project system.

In VS 2017, there are two project systems that can be used for .NET Projects - the "legacy" project system and the new CPS-based project system. Which one is used is determined by a selection logic that looks at the project file (at the moment it looks if there is a `TargetFramework` property defined in the project file itself) or by using a special GUID inside the .sln file.

While it is possible to load classic .NET projects using the new project system, it lacks some capabilities that are available to .NET Framework projects in the legacy one. The most notable ones are designer support for WinForms, WPF and Entity Framework.

It is also not possibly to (productively) use classic ASP.NET projects on the new project system since it will lack all ASP.NET specific features.

So unless a new version of VS uses a new CPS-based project system for classic ASP.NET apps, you will have to unload your project file in order to edit it.

Answer (score -1):

To edit your `.csproj` file, you must to convert it to the 2017 version.

Try to use [this tool](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017) to auto convert.

Comment: Thanks, I'll discuss it with our tech lead.